# What is the best way to find the position of the last occurrence for a specific item?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

Something like this but inverse:

```
int pos = find(v.begin(), v.end(), item) - v.begin();
```

Comment: What is the container?

Comment: the container is a std::vector<int>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `std::find` but use the reverse iterators provided by your container:

```
auto it = std::find(v.rbegin(), v.rend(), item);
int index = v.rend() - it + 1;
```

You need the `+1` because `v.rend()` "points" to element -1, i.e. one "past" the first element.

Answer (score 1):

Use [reverse iterators](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/rbegin/):

```
find(v.rbegin(), v.rend(), item);
```